# How do you make a Ajax Post to a Handler.ashx safe and stop the handler being called directly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

In a Website environment how do you make an ajax post to Handler.ashx secure and how do you stop people calling that handler.ashx directly and putting rubbish in and possibly breaking things server side?

With firefox and firebug you can pretty much hack the post quickly and easily.

I was thinking of these ideas.

1. In the handler check if you are logged in.
2. List item on the load of the site create a unique ID is saved as a cookie and
   when the handler is called then that ID must exist in the Ajax and
   the handler
3. List item the ajax call must come from a certain page

Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: your 1 would be handled by the normal authentication stack. You can include caller.isinrole-style checks for specific authorizations as well. You can use a cookie or a token value created in the page to satisfy 2, but that is best for catching duplicate calls rather than validation. The only way to protect against potentially damaging fuzzing calls is with input validation at the entry point to the API you're protecting - in this case in the HTTPHandler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use authentication ([Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9), [Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh), etc) and validate your input.

**Slightly longer answer**

If your site is configured with an authentication provider, your handler will follow the same rules.

You should always validate any user input or web service input. Don't assume that your client is giving you pristine input. As you have mentioned, anyone with basic web development skills can spoof a POST. Keep that in mind when validating.

Comment: @Hello-World - Windows auth and Forms auth ARE for asp.net web applications. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984546/setting-autorization-rules-for-ashx-handler-in-asp-net-mvc-3-application

Comment: ...and even with authentication someone can still hack the post and send rubbish in.

Comment: If your validation doesn't catch some spoofed rubbish, you can log the user and revoke their access.

Comment: but they might have already cause allot of damage. There must be a more bullet proof way?

Comment: Validate better? If someone already has an account, and is wreaking havoc, that's not necessarily a software problem. All you can do is try to prevent malicious data with validation. But there is no bullet proof solution that I know of ...