# Display base64 image using generic handler(ashx)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, base64, ashx

I am trying to display base64 using generic handler but not getting success. Here is my code of generic handler:

```
public class UserProfilePhoto : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {

                if (UserSession.Get().UserPhoto == null)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                    context.Response.WriteFile("~/assets/img/avatar.png");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.Substring(0, UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.IndexOf(","));
                    context.Response.Write(UserSession.Get().UserPhoto);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling on view-page like below:

```
<img alt="Photo" ng-src="UserProfilePhoto.ashx" />
```

It's not changing src of img tag. I don't know what is wrong. help. [Here is the base64 string which I am getting from database.](http://paste2.org/_ygYjs6tz)

Comment: Check this http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/

Comment: @malkam I need to render a base64 image which is stored as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was in my base64 string. It has content type added with it.  So i removed it and it is working fine using BinaryWrite.

```
context.Response.ContentType = UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.Substring(0, UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.IndexOf(","));
var imageBytes = UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.Substring(UserSession.Get().UserPhoto.IndexOf(",")+1);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(imageBytes));
```

Comment: How can I secure `UserProfilePhoto`? Do you have any idea? Like in Mvc controller we use `[Authorize]`. Is there any way to secure ?

Comment: @AjayPunekar I haven't try it but yes you can try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984570/1624583

Comment: Ok thank you for reply. Yesterday I created one `ActionResult` to show user photo. But I am calling this `ActionResult` from controller. I have a question i.e. how can I call `UserProfilePhoto` class. I have built web api. I am trying to call  `UserProfilePhoto` class from client side. How can I call ?

Comment: @AjayPunekar as written in my question, Use <img alt="Photo" ng-src="UserProfilePhoto.ashx" /> for displaying. And make sure u create your ashx file in the soluion, not in any folder of the solution.

Comment: Oh ok I have created this in folder. That's why I am not able to call this method. I will try. :)